# Python Iterating Values

Tags: python

I want to take iterating values like in the first example.

when i run this code:

```
import numpy as np

import math

angle=np.arange(0.1,10,1)

for d in angle:

    r=(d*np.pi)/180

    c=math.cos(r)

    print(c)
```

output is iterating

when i run this code:

```
import numpy as np
import math

angle=np.arange(0.1,10,1)
for d in angle:
    r=(d*np.pi)/180
    c=math.cos(r)


print(c)
```

I have only a value. How can i have a iterating as in the first example for output  ?

Comment: "print" must be in the loop (indentation).

Answer (score 1):

you should define c as list and append the value to that c.

```
In [11]: import numpy as np
    ...: import math
    ...: c = []
    ...: angle=np.arange(0.1,10,1)
    ...: for d in angle:
    ...:     r=(d*np.pi)/180
    ...:     c.append(math.cos(r))
    ...:

In [12]: c
Out[12]:
[0.9999984769132877,
 0.9998157121216442,
 0.9993283937786562,
 0.9985366703262117,
 0.997440782930944,
 0.9960410654107695,
 0.9943379441332046,
 0.9923319378854887,
 0.9900236577165575,
 0.9874138067509114]
```